# Pyautogui problems

Tags: python, error-handling

Recently I was working with the module pyautogui when I got an error, at first I dismissed it but then when I tried to run other programs the same error, referring to the pyautogui program popped up even though the other program had nothing to do with pyautogui. This was all in VSC, so after opening and closing VSC a few times and the error still occurred when I imported any module I decided to build my programs in terminal instead. **The same error shows up.** Below I have pasted the error from my terminal which will still not allow me to make any python module import whatsoever. Any help is greatly appreciated.
I have upgraded, uninstalled, and reinstalled everything and still the same

```
>>> import random
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Aezene\random.py", line 15, in <module>
   StartLocation = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Start.png')
  File "C:\Users\Aezene\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", 
line 175, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aezene\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", 
line 213, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aezene\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", 
line 359, in locateOnScreen
    screenshotIm = screenshot(region=None) # the locateAll() function must handle cropping to return 
accurate coordinates, so don't pass a region here.
  File "C:\Users\Aezene\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", 
line 134, in wrapper
    raise PyScreezeException('The Pillow package is required to use this function.')
pyscreeze.PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function.
>>>
```

Comment: If you follow the error message, the answer is here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782056/pyautogui-screenshot-function-doesnt-recognize-installed-pillow-module

Comment: This is the error the error that is being flaged `The Pillow package is required to use this function.`. If the above does not help, then you can do searches around this.  PIL is not as straightforward as other packages.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you haven't downloaded the "Pillow" package. You can download by using the command "pip install Pillow" or by using the following code:

```
from subprocess import *
from sys import *

call([executable, "-m", "pip, "install", "Pillow"])
```

You need to have this module because pyautogui's code won't run without it. If you install PyCharm and look at PyAutoGui's file code, you'll see that it is necessary to install the module